# Does someone know how to use PagerTitleStrip in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I decided to use a `ViewPager` in my application and everything is working fine. 
I Know that I want to use a `PagerTitleStrip` in my `ViewPager`, but I've failed to find any info on how to do it...
The one and only page (sic!!) I found on this class is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html
So it seems I just need to add the `PagerTitleStrip` within my `ViewPager` layout, but I don't see anything new on my activity...

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pagerTitleStrip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Does anyone know how to use it?

Edited:
Sorry it works when implementing the `getPageTitle` method in the `ViewPagerAdapter`... but I don't want any text displayed, just a small cursor to show the position of the current View compared to the previous and next ones...

Answer (score 46):

I'm not sure what causing error in your case but this is how I use it, in your layout you should insert following code in your layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Then you should add the following code in your PageAdapter:

```
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position) {
            return "Your static title";
        }
```

That's pretty it.

Comment: It works pretty well... it's not the best in terms of customization but it does its job. This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too where the PagerTitleStrip was not visible.   The answers above did not help.  The problem was that I followed the example on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);
```

The code above shows the view pager but not the PagerTitleStrip.

I changed the code to

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceData) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceData);
    setTitle(R.string.my_title);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_pager);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

res/layout/my_pager.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I was also able to be backward compatible to API 8 by removing all the code in the ViewPager (javadoc page) example to manipulate the ActionBar and ActionBar.Tab.

Answer (score -1):

PagerTitleStrip is a non-interactive signal of the current, next, and former pages of a ViewPager. It really is designed to be used as a child view of a ViewPager widget

Step 1. Create layout activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.androidviewpagerapp.MainActivity" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/titlestrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Step 2. Create Activity contains ViewPager this (MainActvity.java)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ViewPager viewPager;
 MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
  myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
  viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
  PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip)findViewById(R.id.titlestrip);
 }
}
```

Demo : http://photo-wonder.blogspot.com/2016/09/pagertitlestrip-on-viewpager-android.html