# Adding titles to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have set up a ViewPager for swipeable tabs and now I want to add titles at the top of the page to indicate what fragment is being shown.

This is the code so far:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

        // Add fragments here
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, PickerFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, DisplayFragment.class.getName()));

        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    }

}
```

**PageAdapter.java**

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

This works and I am able to swipe between the two tabs but there are no titles.

I want to end up with something that looks like this:

[image: Google play]

I would appreciate any help on how I could set this up.

Comment: You want a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html (google it for a tutorial, it's pretty easy to setup). Have a look at https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator if you want something fancier.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After looking [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html), as suggested in the comments, I did the following:

I added a **PagerTitleStrip** in **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in **PageAdapter.java** I added the following method:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Title Here";
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how to change the color of the titles?  I want a different color per page and I have only figured out how to apply style which changes color for all.  Thanks.

Comment: @cjayem13 You can just use "setTabIndicatorColor" I think. Thing is, I don't know how to do other things with it, such as making it look like the contacts app of Lollipop: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27621425/878126

Comment: How do you change the titles for the individual views?

Comment: @bluemunch You could have a list of strings containing all the different tab titles and then use `titlesList.get(position)` or something similar.

Answer (score 8):

Since Android Support [Design library 22.2.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), you can use `TabLayout` class. It's very similar to `PagerTitleStrip`, you just need to specify title on ViewPagerAdapter.

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titleList.get(position);
}
```

and add it in anywhere in your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly, tie your `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` together.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

In my opinion, it looks nicer than `PagerTitleStrip`. `TabLayout` also suitable for Google Play-like tabs. If you want to do customization like @cjayem13 said (change tab color, text color, selected color etc.), it's very easy to achieve.. see [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) or [CodePath's guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout) for further detail.

Comment: Thanks, this is way nicer visually out of the box!

Answer (score 2):

The main trics is that nested viewpager. A good and descrptive discussion on viewpager and title.
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score -3):

You do not need to implement the adapter by yourself. Simple do following:

```
mPagerAdapter  = new PageAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager() );

mPagerAdapter.addFragment(Fragment.instantiate(this, "Title that you want");
```

And your layout is lacking of PagerTitleStrip, see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597242/does-someone-know-how-to-use-pagertitlestrip-in-android)

The ViewPager is only the container. The PagerTitleStrip should be included in the ViewPager layout, thats for the title.